Assign Global Headers/Parameters to all APIs in Azure APIM
Is there a way to create global headers or parameters that are made available to all APIs in Azure APIM that can then be displayed for each API?


I configured API parameters at the "All API" level, but I don't see them show up for all APIs.
I'm not sure if this is possible or if it has to be done on each individual API request?

No, unfortunately these would need to be added to each API's operation.
